# Better way to conditionally set input value in laravel-blade

Tags: laravel, input, conditional-statements, laravel-blade

I am using this logic to retain value in laravel-blade input form, *THIS WORKS FINE BUT* I am curious if there is any better way to achieve same?

```
 @if(old('name'))
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name') }}">
 @else
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" 
           value="{{ isset($category) ? $category->name : '' }}">
 @endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a second argument to `old`, it will use as default value, so you can have your code like:

```php
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name', isset($category) ? $category->name : '') }}">
```

Still a little ugly, but way better than having that if.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very clean than previous implementation

Comment: No problem ! If you can reduce `isset($category) ? $category->name : ''` to just `$category->name` or `$category->name ?? ''` that would be even better, smaller code !

Comment: $category->name ?? ''    this is very good solution, other is not valid in my case, thanks a lot again for your help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name', isset($category) ? $category->name : '') }}">
```

Comment: I have used:
`<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name', $category->name ?? '') }}">` this very elegant way I found